# How can i check if the node HighExpense exist or not in my Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("HighExpense");
```

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution for that would be to attach a listener and use DataSnapshot`s [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#exists()) method, like in the following lines of code:

```
dr.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //Get data from the dataSnapshot object
        } else {
            //Data is not present
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
});
```